# Add HTML to caption of photo gallery

Tags: jquery, html, image-gallery

I found nice photo gallery with Carousel [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/).

This is very nicely done. I would like to have caption with html tags which is not working for current version.

I tried different thing but didn't work.

how can i make it work as below

```
<a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" data-large="imagelarge.jpg" alt="image" data-description="<b>TITLE</b><br>DATE" /></a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you missed ending quot after data-description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `_showImage` function find the line that says

```
if( title )
    $rgGallery.find('div.rg-caption').show().children('p').empty().text( title );
```

Replace the `text` function on the second line with `html`.

You could further make this functionality optional using another data attribute

```
var skip_escape_html = $thumb.data('skip_escape_html');
```

and then calling a function based on that

```
    $rgGallery.find('div.rg-caption').show().children('p').empty()[ skip_escape_html ? 'html' : 'text' ]( title )
```